# SELECT specific ONLY if exists, otherwise return ALL

Tags: sql, t-sql

How can I write WHERE cluase so it returns rows that meet the criteria, if there are no such records it should return all records from a table?

Comment: Any such query always needs two passes over the table (one to determine if there are rows there, the other to return the desired rows) so if it's easier you may as well do a `IF EXISTS (...)` and write two queries. You can do it in one, of course, by shoving that condition into an `OR`, but be aware that this may well have worse performance.

Comment: The most efficient way would be to simply have a query that selects rows matching your desired criteria and a separate query to returns all rows in the event none match.

Comment: What have you got so far?

Comment: Which is the database?

Answer (score 0):

Using UNION ALL:

```
select t.* from table t where condition
union all
select t.* from table t cross join (select count(*) cnt from table where condition) c
where c.cnt=0
```

Or (much more efficiently):

```
select col1, col2, ... colN
from
(
select t.*, sum(case when condition then 1 else 0 end) over() cnt from table
) s 
where condition or s.cnt=0
```

Replace `condition` with your WHERE condition

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, it was a typo. it should be null instead of 0 or use sum instead of count

Answer (score 0):

One method you could consider in `t-sql` is to use `@@rowcount` to determine if you need to return all rows.

The benefit of doing so is you get two separate execution plans, one only optimised for your first `exists` criteria and would be beneficial if the majority of results are where the `exists` condition is met.

```
select <columns>
from <table>
where <condition>

if @@rowcount=0
begin
  select <columns>
  from <table>
end
```

Comment: This has the considerable drawback of returning either 1 or 2 rowsets, which the client needs to know how to handle. Some transparently merge them, but most libraries/client code will just process the first rowset and be done with it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, yes - the question as posed wasn't particularly clear on the complexity of the criteria. I wouldn't consider this for the "simple" case this transpires to be. If the ctiteria was particularly expensive instead of equality of a simple variable eg, an exists over multiple joins & filtering, the performance trade off of handling a second resultset could be worth it, as usual depending on the use-case.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be:

```
SELECT *
FROM Person
WHERE 
  Name = 'John' 
  OR NOT EXISTS(SELECT null FROM Person WHERE Name = 'John')
```

I don't like it, for all those good reasons mentioned in the comments. If I was handed this requirement as part of a system I was creating I'd probably examine the need for the requirement; selecting all rows from a table is seldom useful if it's the sort of table that you query with a criteria: "Dear user, we couldn't find your person named John so here are the other 4.27 billion users in the system, pagination size 100"

Comment: I agree. But in that specific case the rows returned by select are cursor scope for a store procedure that needs to iterate through specific tables or all existing in configuration table.

Answer (score 0):

that satisfies me enough:

```
WHERE (
           ISNULL(@variable, '') = '' 
           OR @variable = [Column]
           )
```

Not exactly what I described above but it returns all the records if condition is not met. However in that case condition would be assigning a value to variable.

Comment: I was going to suggest something similar, but wasn't certain that the "front end" knew whether it wanted all rows or "some rows" - the requirement read like "the front end only knows it wants 'some rows' but it should be given all rows if no rows match its desires". You can simplify it to `WHERE [Column] = @variable OR @variable IS NULL`

Answer (score 0):

1st method

```
  Where (  ISNULL(@Param,'')='' OR  ColumnName  = @Param)
```

2nd way

```
   WHERE ( ColumnName =CASE WHEN @Param IS NULL THEN ColumnName 
                        ELSE @Param
                        END)
```

3rd way

```
    WHERE (@Param =''  OR @Param =ColumnName)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a CTE with `not exists`:

```
with cte as (
      select t.*
      from t
      where . . .
     )
select *
from cte
union all
select *
from t
where not exists (select 1 from cte);
```